# Writing terminal output to terminal and to a file?

Tags: python

I have different functions which is giving string and text output in the terminal during excecution of the function. The command I have used is `sys.stdout.write`

In one of the function I am creating a file and calling those functions mentioned above. When running this function I need to write all the `sys.output.write` output from different functions in the file as well as to the terminal.

Sample code is like:

```
def func1():
  sys.stdout.write('A')
  sys.stdout.write('B')

def func2():
  sys.stdout.write('C')
  sys.stdout.write('D')
def main():
  fileName=open("log.txt","W+")
  func1()
  func2()
  --------------------
  # need output ABCD both in terminal and write in logfile as well
  # unfortunately cannot change anything in func1() and func2()
```

Comment: Why are you not allowed changing those methods? Also, surely you must have tried out something to see how you can write what you need to a file? Can you show more of your code please?

Comment: need lot of change in the code in i need to change in func1 and func2 :-(

Comment: What is currently happening in your code that is not meeting your expectation?

Comment: in main function i need to show the output of func1() and func2() in terminal as well as write it to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a context manager to create a wrapper that writes to a file and `stdout`:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, log_file_name, stdout):
        self.log_file_name = log_file_name
        self.stdout = stdout

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log_file = open(self.log_file_name, 'a', 0)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.log_file.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.log_file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)
        self.stdout.flush()

def main():
    with Tee('log.txt', sys.stdout) as sys.stdout:
        func1()
        func2()
```

Don't forget to flush `stdout` after each write as it is buffered.

Comment: why use sys.stdout as the alias ?

Comment: @jmugz3: So the code in `func1` and `func2` does not have to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
def func1():
  sys.stdout.write('A')
  sys.stdout.write('B')

def func2():
  sys.stdout.write('C')
  sys.stdout.write('D')



class MyCoolOs:
  def __init__(self,stdout,f):
    self.stdout = stdout
    self.f = f

  def write(self,s):
    self.f.write(s)
    self.stdout.write(s)


def main():
  f=open("log.txt","a")
  sys.stdout = MyCoolOs(sys.stdout,f)
  func1()
  func2()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks Ming, you solution is only writing in file, doesnt write in terminal, i am looking to output both in terminal and file