# context manager I/O operation in file

Tags: python

I am using a context manager to wrap the text which would show in terminal and write to file at the same time.

I faced this problem and got the solution, please check
[Writing terminal output to terminal and to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629435/writing-terminal-output-to-terminal-and-to-a-file)

Cannot change the functions (etc. func1 and func2) problem is after the 'with' statement any output as sys.stdout.write its showing value error: I/O operation in closed file

sample code:

```
import sys, datetime

class FileWrite(object):
    def __init__(self,log_file_name, stdout):

        self.log_file_name = log_file_name
        self.stdout = stdout

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log_file = open(self.log_file_name, 'a', 0)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.log_file.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.log_file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)
        self.stdout.flush()
def func1():
     sys.stdout.write('A')
def func2():
     sys.stdout.write('B')
def main():
    with FileWrite(..........., sys.stdout) as sys.stdout:
        func1()
        func2()



    sys.stdout.write('test')

main()
............................
# both output A and B is showing in terminal and writing in file
............................
# writing 'test' only in terminal......
I/O operation in closed file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need (or want) to use `as` here. If the goal is to convert any write to `sys.stdout` to a write to both `sys.stdout` and your log file, you need to backup `sys.stdout` on `__enter__` and restore it on `__exit__`, but don't explicitly pass `sys.stdout` to the constructor, and don't use the `__enter__` return to replace `sys.stdout`, because that bypasses the `__enter__`/`__exit__` code. Instead, have `__enter__` and `__exit__` do the replacing work for you:

```
class tee_stdout(object):

    def __init__(self, log_file_name):
        self.log_file_name = log_file_name
        self.stdout = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log_file = open(self.log_file_name, 'a', 0)

        # Replace sys.stdout while backing it up
        self.stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout  # Restore original sys.stdout
        self.log_file.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.log_file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)
        self.stdout.flush()
```

Now, usage is just:

```
 with tee_stdout(logfilename):
     ... do stuff that uses sys.stdout, explicitly or implicitly ...
 ... when block exits, sys.stdout restored, so normal behavior resumes ...
```

Note: If you're targeting Python 3.4 or higher, I'd recommend implementing the class with just `write`, and then using `contextlib.redirect_stdout` to avoid reinventing the wheel:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class tee_output:
    def __init__(self, *targets):
        self.targets = targets
    def write(self, data):
        for tgt in self.targets:
            tgt.write(data)
            tgt.flush()

with open(logfilename, 'a') as log, redirect_stdout(tee_output(log, sys.stdout)):
    ... logs to logfilename and sys.stdout when sys.stdout written to ...
... undoes redirection ...
```

Note: All the above aside, usually, you want to just use [the `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and logger methods for stuff like this. You can pre-configure different loggers, some that go to `sys.stdout`, some that go to a log file and `sys.stdout`, some that go just to log files, and use the appropriate one when needed.

Answer (score 1):

`with FileWrite(..........., sys.stdout) as sys.stdout:`

You are overwriting `sys.stdout`, just chose a real name for your file like `output` or whatever but `sys.stdout`.

Example:

```
with FileWrite(..........., sys.stdout) as output:
    output.write('A')
    output.write('B')
sys.stdout.write("test")
```

---

**EDIT**
Since you don't really want to write on the standard output, pass your `FileWrite` instance as parameter to your methods.

```
def func1(output):
    output.write('A')

with FileWrite(..........., sys.stdout) as output:
    func1(output)
```

Do the same for func2.

Comment: can you please give an example

Comment: yes sort of. it doesnt write to file while 'do some writing'

Comment: i have edited my question, sorry, didnt provide every details earlier

Comment: You don't really need your methods, but I edited my answer to match your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124950/discussion-between-mortuzahasan-and-romain-aga).